# Edit svgs instead of recreating

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an apparently simple misunderstanding of d3, and can't find a matching explanation, although lots of stuff I look for seems close.

Basically, I have an array of data, and I want to render a  in an  for each item. I want each  to have its own children elements (a  and a text />) that depends on the datum bound to each .

My problem is that when the data updates, additional  and  elements are added to each , rather than replacing it.

A minimal reproduction codepen is attached. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

https://codepen.io/kamry-bowman/pen/GaLvKJ

html:

```
<body>
  <svg />
  <button>Increment</button>
</body>
```

js:

```
let state = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  state.push({ id: i, value: (i + 1) * 2 });
}

function render() {
  console.log('running', state)
   const svg = d3
      .select("svg")
      .attr("width", "1000")
      .attr("height", "200");

    const gGroup = svg
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(state, d => d.id)
      .join("g")
      .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(${100 * i})`);

    gGroup
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", "50")
      .attr("cy", "50")
      .attr("r", "50")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "black");

    gGroup
      .append("text")
      .text(d => d.value)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("x", "40")
      .attr("y", "55")
      .attr("style", "font: bold 30px sans-serif");
 }

function clickHandler() {
  state = state.map(obj => ({ ...obj, value: obj.value + 1 }))
  render()
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler)

render()
```

I have found a hacky fix of calling gGroup.html(''), but that seems like I'm missing something with how the library is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks very much to @danny buonocore. His answer wasn't quite what I was looking for but it was the most helpful! I found something that matched up at this source: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

The updated codepen that behaves appropriately is here: https://codepen.io/kamry-bowman/pen/GaLvKJ

Comment: His answer is terrible, I don't see why would you have accepted that. The updated codepen seems good, except for one rather minor thing -- you merge new group circles with existing group circles (`(new_g > circle) + (existing_g > circle)`), but a more common approach is to merge groups first, and then take their circles (`(new_g + existing_g) > circle`); you use merge between groups, but you don't reuse that merge later on (if you wish to, you have to save selection returned from `.merge` into a variable)

Comment: Thank you, @CoderinoJavarino, but I am not really following, sorry. Any chance you could do a quick revise of the codepen? For some reason I am not grokking the enter/update/exit phases very well, and the example I used followed the approach here bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add this line directly after you create your svg in the render method:

```
svg.selectAll("*").remove();
```

This will remove all children of the root svg.  Otherwise you'll just keep drawing on top of the same svgs.

[Try it here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBWEXX)

And the docs:

[d3.selectAll()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selectAll)
[selection.remove()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_remove)

---

**EDIT**

To update just the text values themselves, call this `update()` function in the click handler instead:

```
function update() {
  const svg = d3.select("svg")
  d3.selectAll("svg text").each(function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).text(state[i].value);
  });
}
```

The [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBWEXX) has been updated to use this method

---

**EDIT AGAIN**

If you want to bind the values to their `id`, just access it from `d` in `.each()` method instead of `i` (which is the index in the collection):

```
function update() {
  const svg = d3.select("svg")
  d3.selectAll("svg text").each(function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).text(
      state.find((e) => e.id === d.id).value
    );
  });
}
```

Since the entries can be in any order, we'll have to use `Array.find()` to find the element with the matching id. Here's [another codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBWEVK) for this.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this just throw away all the rendered nodes, and re-render everything?

How would I handle this if I had 200 pieces of data, and only one changed for example? Is there a way in d3 that it only updates the changed piece of data without scraping out the whole entry point?

Comment: Yes but in small examples like this, this is usually the easiest method.  I'll update the answer with an approach to only modify the text

Comment: Awesome! Yeah the issue is this is a minimal reproduction of the problem that ties back to a much more complex example with hundreds of nodes and links in a force layout.. I may have simplified too much though

Comment: Okay that's very helpful thanks! I guess I was hoping there was a way to do it where the identity of the bounded groups is persistent regardless of the array order (hence the use of the key function in the .data() call.

Is there a way to do it where the ordering of the array isn't deterministic, and the data binding depends on keys only? So that in this example the values in the 0 and 1 index don't switch? https://codepen.io/kamry-bowman/pen/gJyxER

Comment: Yes, sorry was not aware that's what you were going for.  That `d` parameter contains the data.  Let me update the answer again and hopefully it will be everything you need

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finding more what I was looking for here:  bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 (rtfm apparently!) and implemented as follows: https://codepen.io/kamry-bowman/pen/GaLvKJ. But your answer was very helpful so I did accept it!